# Delete several files in node.js

Tags: node.js

What is the best way to delete several files in node.js?

```
function deleteFiles(files, callback){
    ...
}

var files = ['file1.js', 'file2.jpg', 'file3.css'];
deleteFiles(files, callback);
```

Comment: pretty old question, more recent answer is using fspromises: fspromises.rm(path, {...options}). https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Answer (score 25):

Asynchronous:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function deleteFiles(files, callback){
  var i = files.length;
  files.forEach(function(filepath){
    fs.unlink(filepath, function(err) {
      i--;
      if (err) {
        callback(err);
        return;
      } else if (i <= 0) {
        callback(null);
      }
    });
  });
}

var files = ['file1.js', 'file2.jpg', 'file3.css'];

deleteFiles(files, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('all files removed');
  }
});
```

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/fs.html#file_System

Comment: This should be a example for understanding how callback works

Comment: Nice answer. Async.js could be a nice addition to this, the code snippet above will remove the files in a series fashion, i.e. one after another, async has a nice 'each' method, which would execute all of the file delete commands "at once", and await for them all to finish. Bit more code, but perhaps a lot faster in some circumstances.

Comment: Hi Lee, the code above uses the async variant of fs.unlink and is therefore non-blocking, I.e., the delete will happen "at once" even without using async.js.

Comment: The callback could be called twice: if the first file will throw an error, the `forEach` will continue to run an execute the `fs.unlink`. To fix it the `i--` should be done only if there is no error!

Answer (score 6):

This deletes the files in an array and runs the callback once only after all files have been deleted.

```js
function deleteFiles(files, callback){
  if (files.length==0) callback();
  else {
    var f = files.pop();
    fs.unlink(f, function(err){
      if (err) callback(err);
      else {
        console.log(f + ' deleted.');
        deleteFiles(files, callback);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I personally like **shortcode** (in one line)

```js
files.forEach(path => fs.existsSync(path) && fs.unlinkSync(path))
```

So maybe using **async/await** style it's easier (complete example):

```js
try {
  var files = ['file1.js', 'file2.jpg', 'file3.css'];
  files.forEach(path => fs.existsSync(path) && fs.unlinkSync(path))
  // success code here
} catch (err) {
  // error handling here
  console.error(err)
}
```

Comment: fs.unlinkSync(path) does not return a boolean, put it aside fs.existsSync(path) is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code to delete several files from directory in node.js,

```
var fs = require('fs');

var removeFile= function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("unlink failed", err);
    } else {
        console.log("file deleted");
    }
}

fs.unlink('filepath', removeFile); // for single file


//for multiple files...

_.map(yourArray,(files)=>{
    fs.unlink('filepath', removeFile);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to delete multiple files (for linux env ES6 syntax)

```
import {execSync} from "child_process";
...

...
const files = ['file1.js', 'file2.jpg', 'file3.css'];
// just example path
const rootDir = '/var/www/files/';
if (files.length > 0)
    execSync('rm -f' + files.map(o => rootDir + o.replace(/(\s+)/g, '\\$1')).join(' '));
```

**rm -f** to ignore if files are missing and **replace** to escape spaces if file names contains it,

Answer (score 0):

Best way is delete files synchronously into a loop using `unlinkSync(path)` function ([see the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlinksync_path)), from node `v7.6.0` so far.

Syntax is provided below:

```js
// myListOfFiles will be your list of files with paths relative to your script.
myListOfFiles.forEach(filePath => {
 fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
 return;
});
```

A reference [here](https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/delete-a-file-in-nodejs-using-node-fs/)

Answer (score 0):

> Promisified and slightly improved version Chris answer.

```js
async deleteAll(filePathsList) {
  try {
    await this.deleteFiles(filePathsList);
    logger.log('info', "Following files deleted successfully from EFS --> " + filePathsList.toString());
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.log('error', error.stack || error);
    logger.log('error', "Error occured while deleting files from EFS");
    return false;
  }
}
async deleteFiles(files) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let i = files.length;
    files.forEach(function(filepath) {
      fs.unlink(filepath, function(err) {
        i--;
        if (err && err.code == 'ENOENT') {
          // file doens't exist
          logger.log('info', "Following file doesn't exist, So won't be deleted-->" + (filepath || ''));
        } else if (err) {
          // other errors, e.g. maybe we don't have enough permission
          logger.log('error', "Error occured while deleting the file  " + (filepath || '') + " due to error" + err);
          reject(err);
          return;
        } else if (i <= 0) {
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am currently using and works a treat:

```js
var files = ['file1.js', 'file2.jpg', 'file3.css'];

function deleteFiles(files){
  for (const file of files) {
    fs.unlink((file), err => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  };
}

deleteFiles(files);
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all images to cover directory

```
export const deleteLocallyCovers = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const coverPath = `${process.cwd()}/covers`;
  let files: string[] = fs.readdirSync(coverPath);
  files = files.filter((f) => f !== '.gitkeep');

  const promises = files.map(
    (file) =>
      new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
        fs.unlink(`${coverPath}/${file}`, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
          console.log(`${file} was deleted`);
          resolve();
        });
      }),
  );
  await Promise.all(promises);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that deleting multiple files is quite slow.
Instead of deleting each file individually it's much faster to move the files into a new folder and then remove the folder.

Using rmdirSync is still slow. The following code works much faster...

fs.rm(dir, { recursive: true, force: true }, err => {
if (err) {
throw err
}
console.log(`${dir} is deleted!`)
})

Deleting the folder on the command line is even faster.
You could use nodes child process to run the delete command.
eg "rmdir /s /q C:\files"