# How can I delete multiple files asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fs

Assume I have an array with paths to multiple files. I would like to delete these files asynchronously.

```
var files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'];

fs.unlink(..., callback())
```

I came across with this solution [Delete several files in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295878/delete-several-files-in-node-js) but I think it violates node.js practices (asynchronous function inside a for loop). Is there any other, better solution for this?

Comment: Why would an asynchronous function in a loop violate any nodejs practices? What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: Thank you for your time. @Bergi in a for loop the function launches all the fs.unlink on the background, not leaving them a chance to finish. In my opinion that is ugly, isn't it?

Comment: @VladMatvei: "leaving them a chance to finish" before what? Launching them in the background (unlike `fs.unlinkSync`) is desired, as it speeds up your script by processing them in parallel.

Comment: @VladMatvei The point of asynchronicity is to not to wait till a IO/network operation completes.We should only be worried about how we will get to know once the operation completes. One option is callback. But then we need to explicitly keep track of number of times the callbacks are called. That would make the code highly unreadable and unmaintainable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a an arbitrary list of tasks (unlinking files) asynchronously, but  know when they are all done, you can use the [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) module.  It can run tasks in series and [parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel).

So push all your unlink function calls into an array, then call `async.parallel()` and let them fly.  Then when they are all done, you land in a **single manageble** callback.

```
var files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'];
var myParallelTasks = [];
files.forEach( function( fileName )
{
    myParallelTasks.push( fs.unlink( fileName, function(callback)
    {
       callback();
    })
    );
}

async.parallel( myParallelTasks, function()
{
    // all done
    console.log( "all done" );          
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the option of recursion (code from your link in the question):

```
function deleteFiles(files, callback){
  var i = files.length;
  var file = files.pop();
  if ( file == undefined ) {
    callback();
  } else {
    // do the unlinking ...
    deleteFiles(files, callback);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
async deleteAll(filePathsList) {
  try {
    await this.deleteFiles(filePathsList);
    logger.log('info', "Following files deleted successfully from EFS --> " + filePathsList.toString());
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.log('error', error.stack || error);
    logger.log('error', "Error occured while deleting files from EFS");
    return false;
  }
}
async deleteFiles(files) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let i = files.length;
    files.forEach(function(filepath) {
      fs.unlink(filepath, function(err) {
        i--;
        if (err && err.code == 'ENOENT') {
          // file doens't exist
          logger.log('info', "Following file doesn't exist, So won't be deleted-->" + (filepath || ''));
        } else if (err) {
          // other errors, e.g. maybe we don't have enough permission
          logger.log('error', "Error occured while deleting the file  " + (filepath || '') + " due to error" + err);
          reject(err);
          return;
        } else if (i <= 0) {
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
  })
}
```